# WCF RIA Services POCO Entity properties becoming null after SubmitChanges

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, poco, wcf-ria-services

I have a POCO object in my solution that has some `Entity` objects as properties. I have done this in many other classes, but not when the base class is a POCO as opposed to another `Entity`.

Here is the server side version of the class:

```
public partial class ItemLocationPricingDetail
{
    public ItemLocationPricingDetail()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int ItemLocationDetailId
    {
        get;
        set; //get { return _itemLocationDetail.Id; }                
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int ItemMasterId
    {
        get 
        {
            if (ItemLocationDetail == null) return 0;
            return ItemLocationDetail.ItemMaster.ItemMasterId; 
        }
    }

    private EntityRef<ItemLocationDetail> _itemLocationDetail;
    [DataMember]
    //[Include()]
    //[Association("ParentChild", "ItemLocationDetailId", "Id", IsForeignKey = false)]
    public ItemLocationDetail ItemLocationDetail
    {
        get { return _itemLocationDetail.Entity; }
        set { _itemLocationDetail.Entity = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public ItemMaster ItemMaster
    {
        get 
        {
            if (ItemLocationDetail == null) return null;
            return ItemLocationDetail.ItemMaster; 
        }
        set { ItemLocationDetail.ItemMaster = value; }
    }

    private decimal _newPrice;
    [DataMember]
    public decimal NewPrice
    {
        get { return _newPrice; }
        set { _newPrice = value; }
    }
}
```

I do have a client side partial class, but that doesn't deal with any of these properties.

I also have a meta data class as follows:

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(ItemLocationPricingDetail.ItemLocationPricingDetailMetadata))]
public partial class ItemLocationPricingDetail
{
    internal sealed class ItemLocationPricingDetailMetadata
    {
        [Key]
        public int ItemLocationDetailId { get; set; }

        [Include]
        [Association("ItemLocationDetailAssociation", "ItemLocationDetailId", "Id")]
        public EntityRef<ItemLocationDetail> ItemLocationDetail { get; set; }

        [Include]
        [Association("ItemMasterAssociation", "ItemMasterId", "ItemMasterId")]
        public EntityRef<ItemMaster> ItemMaster { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The issue is that I make a simple modification to a property of the `ItemLocationDetail` property. I then call `SubmitChanges` on the `DataContext` which works perfectly fine. The issue is that after that has completed, *something*, tries to access some of the properties in the `ItemLocationPricingDetail` class, but for some reason the `ItemLocationDetail` is now null. This is why there are null checks on that property throughout the class, just so I can try and see where the issue is, but I can't find the problem.

I am guessing it occurs when the `ItemLocationPricingDetail` class is being updated after the `SubmitChanges` has been called, but I'm unsure of the working of RIA services at that level.

As you can can see there is some commented out code around the `ItemLocationDetail` property, while this compiles and no errors are given, the issue still persists. That is the only information vaguely related to this issue I have found on the internet.

Could anyone make any suggestions? If you need more information I will provide it.

Thanks.